# Is mon chérie grammatically right?

Tags: accord

Is mon chérie grammatically right? It bothers me, shouldn't it be "chéri". Google gave different answers and ChatGPT said it is right?

Comment: Yes, _mon chéri_. If you want an "e" at the end, it has to be _ma chérie_.

Comment: Grammatically in a correct French sentence if you want to say "my darling" it is *mon chéri* or *ma chérie* **but** *mon chérie* exists as different product names (not French ones as far as I know), so  if what you read in google links to one of these products or ChatGPT talks about one of these products they are right.

Comment: @None Thank you this clarified

Comment: @Frank thank you

Comment: @None - des "produits" _mon chérie_? Quel genre de produit?

Comment: @Frank Je ne vais pas faire de (mauvaise) pub. Ton moteur de recherche préféré te montrera certains objects, en plus des fautes de frappe sur des citations pour certains chocolats à la liqueur. j'avais déjà vu un sweat avec ça écrit, et il y a un parfum (les deux ne sont pas français). Et je viens d'en trouver encore pour une collection de  linge de table fait aux Pays-bas qui présente ses produits dans un anglais abominable !!!!

Comment: This has nothing to do with grammar.  It's about agreement (gender, number) between the modifier, a possessive adjective, and a noun.

Comment: @livresque but it is grammar "In linguistics, the grammar of a natural language is its set of structural rules on speakers' or writers' usage and creation of clauses, phrases, and words. The term can also refer to the study of such rules, a subject that includes phonology, morphology, and syntax, together with phonetics, semantics, and pragmatics."

Comment: Grammaticality and grammar are used broadly and often get mixed up.  It's great to ask specific questions about it, just trying to help the question filter more than "is this right?"  You're asking about morphology, too, though you're not asking why.  You can certainly add other tags as you continue your research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual ChatGPT can only correctly answer trivial questions. Here in French *mon chérie* is wrong. Full stop. And AFAIK, it is not even a familiar wording.

You can use *mon* with a feminine noun when the noun starts with a vowel, so *mon amie* is perfectly correct for a girl as would be *mon ami* for a boy.

There are familiar forms like *m'amour*. But I can only imagine *mon chérie* when the author would have a character not fluent in French to say it.